# Single query for POS tagging and tokensregex

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford NLP Web Api to get POS tags and tokensregex queries.
What tokensregex is doing actually finding POS tags behind of scene and execute regex queries over it. 
So I need to hit web api 2 times (in my case one for POS tagging and 2 different tokensregex, 3 times to get result for a sentence)

Is there a way to get POS tags and tokensregex with one query against web api ?
I did not see in the documentation. Maybe undocumented feature or any plan for future ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is planned for the future. There's no inherent reason the tokensregex and semgrex endpoints can't deserialize annotated documents, beyond the fact that I haven't implemented it yet. Pull requests are welcome :)!